# How to create a small box above selected text ( double click to select it )

Tags: javascript

I try to write a dictionary extension for Google Chrome. Now, I want to pop out a small box when I double click to select text . How can I implement it :)
Or like this one ( Fastest Chrome ). They're written in javascript.

[alt text http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/9721/abcjq.jpg](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/9721/abcjq.jpg)
Thanks so much !

Comment: do you want a popup tooltip on selected the text?

Comment: take a look http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp

Comment: if you want tooltips http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create_lightweight_javascript_tooltip/

Comment: Thanks for your answer jjj. You should reply as answers . I 'll check your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two links that may solve your question:

- [Detecting a double-click on a Youtube URL with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241849/detecting-a-double-click-on-a-youtube-url-with-javascript/4241860#4241860) (uses JQuery)
- [Detecting a double-click on a Youtube URL with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241849/detecting-a-double-click-on-a-youtube-url-with-javascript/4241860#4241860) (uses pure JS)

And since no one previously wanted to reply as answers, try the links mentioned above:

- http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp
- http://www.sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/